# Javascript remove row from multidimensional array when elements are duplicated

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have the following array.

```
[{
  'firstname': 'John',
  'surname': 'Smith',
  'HouseNo': 'firtree farm'
}, {
  'firstname': 'Paul',
  'surname': 'Smith',
  'HouseNo': 'firtree farm'
}, {
  'firstname': 'John',
  'surname': 'Smith',
  'HouseNo': 'firtreefarm'
}, {
  'firstname': 'John',
  'surname': 'Smith',
  'HouseNo': 'firtree farmhouse'
}, {
  'firstname': 'Paul',
  'surname': 'Smith',
  'HouseNo': 'firtree farmhouse'
}, {
  'firstname': 'Paul',
  'surname': 'Smith',
  'HouseNo': 'FirTree farmhouse'
}]
```

I need to produce another array that contains no duplicates of element 'HouseNo' and just the element 'HouseNo. Also it need to be case insensitive.

ie.

```
[{
  'HouseNo': 'firtree farm'
}, {
  'HouseNo': 'firtreefarm'
}, {
  'HouseNo': 'firtree farmhouse'
}, {
  'HouseNo': 'FirTree farmhouse'
}]
```

The application is a returned set of address's based on a postcode search. I can then offer a filtered list of unique houseNo's they can choose form.

MrWarby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the already seen items in an object, and if you get an item which is not there in the `seen`, then push it to the `result`.

```
var seen = {};
var result = data.reduce(function(result, current) {
    if (!seen[current.HouseNo]) {
        seen[current.HouseNo] = true;
        result.push(current.HouseNo);
    }
    return result;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ 'firtree farm',
  'firtreefarm',
  'firtree farmhouse',
  'FirTree farmhouse' ]
```

If you want to maintain the object structure, then while pushing to the result, just create an object like this

```
result.push({HouseNo: current.HouseNo});
```

and the result would be

```
[ { HouseNo: 'firtree farm' },
  { HouseNo: 'firtreefarm' },
  { HouseNo: 'firtree farmhouse' },
  { HouseNo: 'FirTree farmhouse' } ]
```

If the Order of the data doesn't matter, then you can simply keep adding the `HouseNo` to an object and finally get the `keys` like this

```
var result = data.reduce(function(result, current) {
    result[current.HouseNo] = true;
    return result;
}, {});
console.log(Object.keys(result));
```